# Why does env exporting with --from-history flag also include packages I've never explicitly installed via conda install?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have installed these packages using the command `conda install`:

```
python=3.11.3
xarray=2023.4.2
rioxarray=0.14.1
netcdf4=1.6.3
geopandas=0.13.2
```

I am trying to ensure a cross-platform environment creation works, so I am using the `--from-history` flag:
`conda env export --from-history -n netC > netC.yml`

The output looks like this:

```
name: netC
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.11.3
  - xarray=2023.4.2
  - rioxarray=0.14.1
  - netcdf4=1.6.3
  - geopandas=0.13.2
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
prefix: <redacted>
```

Why is it adding `ca-certificates`, `certifi`, and `openssl` to the list when I did not `conda install` those? I realize they were installed when I installed as dependencies for the other packages, but I wouldn't think they would show up using `--from-history`.

The solution for me is to simply delete them (you could probably leave them with no affect too, but I want to ensure we're all running the same version number of everything). I'm just wanting to understand what it is doing.

Comment: Probably related to the fact that they are all part of the aggressive updating set. They likely get injected as explicit specifications when a `conda update` or `conda install` command is called. This won’t happen if you specify all packages at creation time and don’t mutate it after.